# Running a Batch file with ant 'build.xml'

Tags: batch-file, ant

I am trying to run a batch file called 'sparql.bat' by using ant build.xml. The last line in the batch file is -

```
java %JVM_ARGS% -Dlog4j.configuration="%LOGGING%" -cp "%JENA_CP%" arq.sparql --data=\apache-jena-2.10.0\test.ttl --query=\apache-jena-2.10.0\testing.rq
```

Where %JVM_ARGS% is -Xmx1024M and the other things can also be replaced.
I am trying to run this using an ant build.xml,  "--data=\apache-jena-2.10.0\test.ttl --query=\apache-jena-2.10.0\testing.rq" are the arguments.
I have prepared the build.xml like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="apache-jena-2.10.0" basedir="." default="notify">
 <target name="notify">
  <java JVM_ARGS="-Xmx1024M" Dlog4j.configuration="%LOGGING%" cp="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\*" arq.sparql="%*">
   <arg data="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\test.ttl"/>
   <arg query="\apache-jena-2.10.0\ASKTest.rq"/>
   <classpath>
       <pathelement location="."/>
   </classpath>
  </java>
</project>
```

Can somebody please help me to write a build.xml file which can execute this?
Thanks
Somsuvra

Answer (score 1):

Try something more along these lines:

```
<java classname="arq.sparql">
   <arg value="--data=C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\test.ttl"/>
   <arg value="--query=C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\testing.rq"/>
   <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M"/>
   <jvmarg value="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties”/>
   <classpath>
      <pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib"/>
   </classpath>
</java>
```

Comment: Hi For this you need to specify all the jat files in the lib directory as pathelement just like this-   <pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\jena-core-2.10.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\jena-arq-2.10.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar"/>

Answer (score 0):

Final solutions is -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="apache-jena-2.10.0" basedir="." default="notify">
<target name="notify">
<java classname="arq.sparql" fork="true">
<arg value="--data=C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\test.ttl"/>
<arg value="--query=C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\ASKTest.rq"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M"/>
<classpath>
<pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\jena-core-2.10.0.jar"/>
<pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\jena-arq-2.10.0.jar"/>
<pathelement location="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
</classpath>
</java>
</target>
</project>
```

Now my question is instead of writing all the .jar files seperately is there any way of specifying them in a single line.

Thanks and regards

Somsuvra

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the pathelement elements with a fileset. Something like this:

```
<fileset dir="C:\apache-jena-2.10.0\lib">
   <include name="**/*.jar"/>
</fileset>
```